# When and to whom was Psalm 45 written?

Tags: psalms, authorship

Psalm 45 is one of the most mysterious and bizarre compositions of the book of Psalms; it speaks about an anonymous king and his sensuous wives, and goes into great detail about his wealth, power and lust. What I find most interesting are verses 10-14 (NJPS),

> Take heed, lass, and note, incline your ear: forget your people and
>   your father's house,  and let the king be aroused by your beauty;
>   since he is your lord, bow to him. O Tyrian lass, the wealthiest
>   people will court your favor with gifts,

Unfortunately, the author has not included an introduction to this chapter, so we are left in the dark as to whom this poem is addressed and for which occasion it was composed (However the redactor does identify it as a love song in the beginning verse; *shir yedidoth*). It exhorts an anonymous woman/daughter to forget her home and family, so that the king may be aroused by her beauty (and perhaps accept her as his consort), and then identifies her as a Tyrian woman. How did a Tyrian lass make it into a Hebrew Psalm, and what is the background for this composition?

---

I am aware that some translate the words *ubath tzor* (lit. daughter of Tyre) differently; that is, instead of 'O Tyrian lass' they have 'and the city of Tyre', thus leaving the subject in this verse unidentified (they will bring *you* gifts). However, the Masoretic sign *paseq* strongly supports the interpretation of the NJPS as its purpose here is clearly to separate and break up these words from the following words, see [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13732/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-paseq-in-genesis-1-5) for similar uses of the paseq. So, in this case it is more correct to read the words *ubath tzor* as addressing the subject already mentioned in verse 11 (take heed, lass)--that the wealthy people will bring her gifts--than to take it as a reference to the city of Tyre which will bring gifts to the anonymized woman. (However see commentary of K&D).

Comment: related: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/5521/interpretation-of-psalm-4514?rq=1

Comment: '_Thou art fairer than the children of men_' is the key to whom it is addressed.

Answer (score 4):

I find the theory of [Keil and Delitzsch](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/kad/psalms/45.htm) most compelling, that the Psalm was composed in honor of the marriage of Jehoram of Judah with [Athaliah](http://http:/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athaliah). This lady was a daughter of Ahab king of Israel who married the Tyrian princess Jezebel, and was in some way a Tyrian lass through her mother's side and the Tyrian upbringing she received. This convincingly explains the reference to the Tyrian lass in connection with the Davidic (Messianic) king of Judah. That this Psalm was composed in connection with Ahab's marriage to Jezebel, set forth by Hitzig, is rejected straight out by Keil "by the fact that the poet idealizes the person celebrated, as foreshadowing the Messiah, in a way that can only be justified in connection with a Davidic king." The author also rejects any connection between this composition and king Solomon because of the absence of any mention of Egypt (Solomon married an Egyptian princess). Then the author goes on,

> All this speaks against Solomon, but just with equal force in favour
>   of Joram, as being the king celebrated. This Joram is the son of
>   Jehoshaphat, the second Solomon of the Israelitish history. He became
>   king even during the lifetime of his pious father, under whom the
>   Salomonic prosperity of Israel was revived (cf. 2 Chronicles 18:1 with
>   Psalm 21:3, 2 Kings 8:16, and Winer's Realwrterbuch under Jehoram); he
>   was also married to Athaliah during his father's lifetime; and it is
>   natural, that just at that time, when Judah had again attained to the
>   height of the glory of the days of Solomon, the highest hopes should
>   be gathered around these nuptials. This explains the name שׁגל which
>   the queen bears, - a name that is elsewhere Chaldaean (Daniel 5:2.)
>   and Persian (Nehemiah 2:6), and is more North-Palestinian than Jewish;
>   for Athaliah sprang from the royal family of Tyre, and was married by
>   Joram out of the royal family of Israel. **If she is the queen, then the
>   exhortation to forget her people and her father's house has all the
>   greater force. And it becomes intelligible why the homage of Tyre in
>   particular, and only of Tyre, is mentioned.**

Comment: Wow, that really clears up a lot. Thanks Bach! Also, Solomon was not a warrior!

Comment: I took more time to read the link and it is extremely difficult to follow. Is is Jehoshaphat's son Jehoram, king of Judah or his son-in-law Joram, son of Ahab? It appears to me that he favors Joram as a candidate, no? But see *Matthew 1:8
ASV(i) 8 and Asa begat Jehoshaphat; and Jehoshaphat begat Joram; and Joram begat Uzziah;*

Comment: Please see: https://studybible.info/thompson-chain/JEHORAM

Comment: @Ruminator "I find the theory of Keil and Delitzsch most compelling, that the Psalm was composed in honor of the marriage of Jehoram of Judah with Athaliah." K&D make it also abundantly clear that it is in honor of the king of Judah that this Psalm was composed. I'm not sure wherein lies your confusion.

Comment: From the section you quoted: *All this speaks against Solomon, but just with equal force in favour of Joram, as being the king celebrated. This Joram is the son of Jehoshaphat, the second Solomon of the Israelitish history.*

Comment: Both theories (Athaliah and Jezebel) work for me. IMO the poem has evolved from its original so it is not easy to separate it from its current mystical and messianic references.  It's amazing to think that a psalm celebrating divine hope in the marriage of either of the bible's two most infamous evil queens has survived. An alliance between Israel and Judah is particularly intriguing in the case of Athaliah, daughter of Ahab.

Answer (score 0):

The psalm does not sing of an ancient king of Israel, but of a warrior of God that the sons of Kohath styled as kingly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/51203)